# Not able to open Eclipse after installing jdk11

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded the JDK 11
changed the build path in the eclipse.

My eclipse version is 4.7.

Then installed jenkins
but in Jenkins the build was failing and then when I tried to to open the eclipse it is giving the below error. I am not able to open the eclipse

please find the POM file details:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.crm.qa</groupId>
  <artifactId>FreeCRMProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FreeCRMProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

please fnd the details of log file

```
 !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-06-22 09:41:44.111
    !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at 
    
    
    
    !SESSION 2020-06-22 09:42:04.771 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.7.2.M20171130-0510
    java.version=11.0.7
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-06-22 09:42:07.046
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
```

Comment: That version of Eclipse will not run with Java 11, you need to run a newer version such as the current Eclipse 2020-06 or go back to Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the issue of selenium. So I request you before posting any question please choose the tags properly. Let's talk about the issue. It is the known bug in eclipse. As you are using older version of eclipse that is why you are facing that issue. Could you please upgrade your eclipse to Eclipse 2018-09 and check whether it resolves your issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9, Java runtime changed in non backward compatible way and support for those changes are not available in older versions of Eclipse.

It is suggested that you upgrade your eclipse to 4.7.3 or newer versions.